# Saltstack Jinja template pillar merge

Tags: salt, jinja

I have a several pillars and I am trying to merge them in the same jinja variable

```
{%- import_yaml "server_list_de.yaml" as servers %}
{%- import_yaml "server_list_uk.yaml" as servers_uk %}
{%- servers.update(servers_uk) %}
```

but I've got following error:

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/utils/context.py", line 211, in __getitem__
return self._dict()[key]
KeyError: '_errors'
```

Answer (score 1):

The "saltey" way of doing this is typically in a map.jinja file. [This one](https://github.com/jdshewey/salt-formula-freeipa/blob/master/freeipa/map.jinja) for example...

In that, you would:

```
{%- load_yaml as serverlist %}
#Note that a default list could be provided here
{%- endload %}

{%- set serverlist2 = salt['grains.filter_by'](serverlist, merge=salt['pillar.get']('pillarname:server_list_de')) %}
{%- set servers = salt['grains.filter_by'](serverlist2, merge=salt['pillar.get']('pillarname:server_list_uk')) %}
```

Then in your sls file you would then put at the top:

```
{%- from "formulaname/map.jinja" import servers with context %}
```

Servers should then be available to you. I've never tried merging twice though, so give it a try. At a minimum this may give you some direction as the syntax for doing a pillar merge like this may get you what you are looking for.